# Android- Media player Shows error at current = mp.getCurrentPosition();

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, fatal-error

I am trying to make a media player to play music. But after playing 3-4 songs it stops. And gives following error.
And I am getting the error exactly at `current = mp.getCurrentPosition();`
My code is:

```
public class player extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ArrayList<File> mysong;
    static MediaPlayer mp;
    SeekBar sb;
    int position;
    Uri u;
    TextView tv;
    Thread updateseek;
    Button btplay, btFF, btBB, btnext, btpreviout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        sb = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        btplay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btFF = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button3);
        btBB = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        btnext = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button5);
        btpreviout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button4);
        tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        btpreviout.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnext.setOnClickListener(this);
        btBB.setOnClickListener(this);
        btFF.setOnClickListener(this);
        btplay.setOnClickListener(this);

        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
        }

        updateseek = new Thread(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int total = mp.getDuration();
                int current = 0;
               sb.setMax(total);
                while(current < total){
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                        current = mp.getCurrentPosition();
                        sb.setProgress(current);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                super.run();
            }
        };



        Intent i = getIntent();
        Bundle b = i.getExtras();
        mysong = (ArrayList) b.getParcelableArrayList("mysonglist");
        position = b.getInt("pos", 0);

        u = Uri.parse(mysong.get(position).toString());
        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.start();
        sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
        updateseek.start();

        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.release();
            }
        });


        sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                    if(sb.getProgress()>(mp.getDuration()/2)){
                        tv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }else tv.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                btplay.setText("p");
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    mp.seekTo(seekBar.getProgress());
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                if (mp.isPlaying()) {
                    mp.pause();
                } else mp.start();
                break;

            case R.id.button2:
                mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition() - 5000);
                break;

            case R.id.button3:
                mp.seekTo(mp.getCurrentPosition() + 5000);
                break;

            case R.id.button4:
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                position = (position - 1 < 0) ? mysong.size() - 1 : (position - 1) % mysong.size();
                u = Uri.parse(mysong.get(position).toString());
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
                sb.setProgress(0);
                mp.start();
                sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                break;

            case R.id.button5:
                mp.stop();
                mp.release();
                position = (position + 1) % mysong.size();
                u = Uri.parse(mysong.get(position).toString());
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), u);
                sb.setProgress(0);
                mp.start();
                sb.setMax(mp.getDuration());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

My log cat is here:

> 12-18 18:04:37.483 4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer
>   W/Resources: Converting to string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3
>   r=0x7f0c0057} 12-18 18:04:37.483
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/Resources: Converting to
>   string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0c0058} 12-18 18:04:37.493
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/Resources: Converting to
>   string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0c0072} 12-18 18:04:37.493
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/Resources: Converting to
>   string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0c0073} 12-18 18:04:37.493
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer D/AbsSeekBar: AbsSeekBar
>   Constructor: mAllowedSeeBarAnimation = false 12-18 18:04:37.503
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/Resources: Converting to
>   string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0c0074} 12-18 18:04:37.503
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/Resources: Converting to
>   string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0c0075} 12-18 18:04:37.503
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/Resources: Converting to
>   string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0c0076} 12-18 18:04:37.513
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/Resources: Converting to
>   string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0c0077} 12-18 18:04:37.513
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/Resources: Converting to
>   string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0c0078} 12-18 18:04:37.513
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/Resources: Converting to
>   string: TypedValue{t=0x12/d=0x0 a=3 r=0x7f0c0079} 12-18 18:04:37.513
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer I/MediaPlayer: sendBroadcast
>   CONTEXT_AWARE_MUSIC_INFO - type(stop) - id(573) 12-18 18:04:37.633
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer E/MediaPlayer-JNI:
>   QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present 12-18 18:04:37.693
>   4846-4856/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/MediaPlayer: info/warning
>   (973, 0) 12-18 18:04:37.703 4846-5528/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-26716
>                                                                                  Process: com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer, PID: 4846
>                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException
>                                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer.player$1.run(player.java:65) 12-18
>   18:04:37.703 4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer E/MediaPlayer:
>   Should have subtitle controller already set 12-18 18:04:37.813
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer D/PhoneWindow: *FMB*
>   isFloatingMenuEnabled mFloatingMenuBtn : null 12-18 18:04:37.813
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer D/PhoneWindow: *FMB*
>   isFloatingMenuEnabled return false 12-18 18:04:37.843
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer D/SRIB_DCS: log_dcs
>   ThreadedRenderer::initialize entered!  12-18 18:04:37.863
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer I/MediaPlayer: Don't send
>   intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0 12-18 18:04:37.863
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer E/MediaPlayer: Should have
>   subtitle controller already set 12-18 18:04:37.883
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer I/MediaPlayer: send context
>   aware event 12-18 18:04:37.893
>   4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer I/MediaPlayer: sendBroadcast
>   CONTEXT_AWARE_MUSIC_INFO - type(start) - id (574) 12-18 18:04:39.623
>   4846-5528/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer I/Process: Sending signal.
>   PID: 4846 SIG: 9
>
> **12-18 18:04:37.633 4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer E/MediaPlayer-JNI: QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present 12-18
>   18:04:37.693 4846-4856/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer W/MediaPlayer:
>   info/warning (973, 0) 12-18 18:04:37.703
>   4846-5528/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL
>   EXCEPTION: Thread-26716
>                                                                                  Process: com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer, PID: 4846
>                                                                                  java.lang.IllegalStateException
>                                                                                      at android.media.MediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition(Native Method)
>                                                                                      at com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer.player$1.run(player.java:65) 12-18
>   18:04:37.703 4846-4846/com.bucketlist.dell.musicplayer E/MediaPlayer:
>   Should have subtitle controller already set**

Answer (score 0):

While developing a music player I got the same exception, The root cause of the issue is calling mp.getCurrentPosition () from a wrong state.

Your starting updateseek from oncreate and it runs continuously, if one song completed and you're trying to play the next song in that time media player in stop state at that time your trying to call getCurrentPosition it trigger the exception.

So add an if condition (mp.isPlaying) before calling mp.getCurrentPosition () and make sure that song is playing while calling getCurrentPosition().